# using the j query in the angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am going to use j query for animated loading but it is not working in index.html on angular 2..

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $(window).load(function()
                {


                $('#loader').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); });

                });
```

Comment: is there any way to add the jquery in html page in angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [this post](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0).